# Transition of the same html element between two pages

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have four different html pages and I am trying to do an animation with the same html element (a circle).
How can i have a smooth transition from the one page to another(scrolling or clicking a link) showing that the element animates from the one place to the other and not that it just loads there? Is that possible without a javascript framework?

Example

Page 1

```
<div class="circlepage1"></div>



.circlepage1{
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 0.09em solid #707070;
        position: absolute;
        top: 313px;
        right: 688px;
    }
```

Page 2

```
<div class="circlepage2"></div> 




.circlepage2{
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    position: fixed;
    right: 130px;
    top: 220px;

}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible without using any kind of javascript. You need to change the state of an element somehow. How should you do that without javascript? Javascript brings interaction to a page. It's the electric wires in a house built by HTML and colored/styled by CSS.

Comment: Things like these will likely be possible soon with pure CSS using "CSS View Transitions Module Level 1", currently a candidate recommendation. See e. g. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-view-transitions-1/#example-71838070 -- Current state of experimental browser support: https://wpt.fyi/results/css/css-view-transitions?label=experimental&label=master&aligned

Comment: ... this needs pure CSS and some vanilla JS, no "javascript framework"

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving static HTML pages then as far as I'm aware it is not possible to 'share' one element between two pages. If you're clicking a link to transition between pages, you could:

1. Add an `onClick` event listener to the link to intercept the page change with `event.preventDefault()`.
2. Attach `document.location.href = nextPageUrl` to an `animationEnd` event listener on the element.
3. Animate the element so that it matches the appearance of the comparative element on the next page.